# How can I change a URL after reloading a module?

Tags: reactjs

So I am making a Course Management application that allows me to render a list of modules for a particular course and a list of lessons for a particular module.

When I try to delete a particular lesson, my service file on the client side tries to fetch the URL for the lesson that I just deleted. It returns an error:

> Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input

My friend advised me to use `this.props.history.push` to remove the lesson part from the URL and just reload the URL that contains the module.

This is my function for deleting the lesson:

```js
deleteLesson(lessonId) {
    let popupWindow = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this lesson?");
    if (popupWindow) {
        this.lessonService
            .deleteLesson(lessonId)
            .then(() => {
                this.findAllLessonsForModule(this.state.courseId, this.state.moduleId);
                this.props.history.push(`http://localhost:8080/course/${this.state.courseId}/module/${this.state.moduleId}`);
            });
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is that once I delete a lesson with a particular lesson ID, I reload all the lessons for that module again, after which I want to change the URL.

How should I go about this?

Comment: I did.It returns a "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" error!

Comment: That's because the history of your router isn't binded to this component. You should read the [react router history docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/history)

Comment: I tried to read the docs but I'm confused. Can you please help?

Comment: @OnurDoğan Please do not format text which is not code in code formatting. See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/215552) for more info.